# Time sensitive push only works after reinstall

Tags: ios, ios15

I was implementing time sensitive (remote) push notifications for my app. Which works when I delete the previous version and install the new version.
However, it does not work when updating the app from the older version to the newer one which supports time sensitive notifications.

I have enabled Time Sensitive Notifications in the developer console and the entitlement file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.usernotifications.time-sensitive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've not released the app to the app store, I was testing with Testflight.
But it also happend when installing through xcode.

This is the content of the notification

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Reward", "sound": "default", "interruption-level": "time-sensitive"}, "type": "reward", "rewardText": "Cool dude", "rewardPoints": 200}
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: I was trying to figure out why my app wasn't displaying Time Sensitive notifications, and your answer helped me realize that I needed to reinstall to see the results, so thanks for that. As far as your question goes, I will note that the Microsoft Outlook app has had Time Sensitive Notifications ever since I upgraded to iOS 15, and I didn't reinstall Outlook or anything—it must have been pushed out in an update of theirs. That gives me the hope that when you or I push our apps to the App Store, the users won't need to reinstall.